# Cannot redeclare get_tag()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress

I want to add this array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $outlet_name[] = $row['outlet_name'];
      $town[] = $row['town']; 
    }
```

to a variable like this

```
var availableTags = [
        "abc",
        "bcd",
        "cde",
        "def"
    ];
```

I read some stackoverflow answers and got this code

```
<?php
            function get_tag($value) {
                return $value['tag'];
            }
            echo json_encode(array_map("get_tag", $Tags));
        ?>
```

But after i put this code it gives me this error

```
Cannot redeclare get_tag() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\miss_sri_lanka_australia\wp-includes\category.php:306) in C:\wamp\www\miss_sri_lanka_australia\wp-content\themes\miss_sri_lanka_australia\header.php on line 63
```

I'm using "WordPress 3.8.3" If anyone can help me with this I'm very appreciate it

Comment: exactly as the error says

Comment: First code block is PHP, second is Javascript. You should only declare a PHP function if it doesn't exist already (and it looks like a Wordpress function...)

Comment: If I doesn't use third block code...how should i do it?

Comment: So, why don't you just give it a different name?

Comment: @ JLRishe I did but it doesn't read the database. Actually I'm new to php & js. So i don't know lots of ways to do this